# Why does Inspector developer tool not reflect all code?

Tags: javascript, html, cytoscape.js

Following [this tutorial](http://blog.js.cytoscape.org/2016/05/24/getting-started/), I am trying to include cytoscape.js into a super basic web page. I downloaded cytoscape via `npm install cytoscape`, and copied `cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.js` into my project directory. The directory looks like:

```
Kyles-MBP:Desktop kyleweise$ tree testing-cytoscape/
testing-cytoscape/
├── cytoscape.js
└── index.html
```

I have basically copied what appears in the tutorial, and `index.html` looks like:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Tutorial 1: Getting Started</title>
  <script src="cytoscape.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #cy {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
    <script>
      var cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),
        elements: [
          { data: { id: 'a' } },
          { data: { id: 'b' } },
          {
            data: {
              id: 'ab',
              source: 'a',
              target: 'b'
            }
          }]
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I try to view the file via a web browser (I've tried Chrome, Safari, and Firefox), I see nothing. When I view the developer tools in whichever browser, the HTML does not match that of my `index.html` file. Specifically, the `<meta charset = "UTF-8">` does not show up, and the `<body>` tag is empty. I am very new to web development and JavaScript, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Why doesn't the `index.html,` when viewed in the browser, match what I have written in my text editor and how can I get this to display the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct.

Anyway I suggest to use the citoscape cdn:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.14/cytoscape.js

or

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.14/cytoscape.min.js for the minified version.

and it works

```js
var cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),
        elements: [
          { data: { id: 'a' } },
          { data: { id: 'b' } },
          {
            data: {
              id: 'ab',
              source: 'a',
              target: 'b'
            }
          }]
      });
```

```css
    #cy {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.14/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<div id="cy"></div>
```

Comment: Weird that this works here, but I changed the `<script>` in the `<head>` to look at that URL and still nothing. It's like the browser does not recognize that I modified the file.

Comment: is javascript enabled in your browser?

Comment: Yes, just went to Chrome settings and JavaScript is set to allowed.

Comment: Ahhhhh I got it. I was modifying one `index.html` file and pulling up another version in my browser. Thank you!